# Why is that the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function become ever more frequent with increasing $|t|$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I understand that, as one climbs the critical line, $\sigma = 1/2$, with increasing $|t|$, the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, $s = \sigma + i \, t$, become ever more frequent. The number of zeros in between zero and $T$, $0 < |t| < T$, is roughly proportional to $T \, {\rm log} \, T$, so that the mean distance between these non-trivial zeros is ever decreasing.

I'm interested in the reason why is that so. I'm not interested in observations, as there are many available out there, what I'm interested in is the root cause for this density increase.

Comment: The basic reason is that $\log |\zeta(-2n-1)|$ is about $\log (2n)!$ by the functional equation, which means that the entire function $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is (at least) of order one and maximal type (the functional equation also implies that it is exactly of that order/type) so by general theory the number of zeroes up to height $T$ is $cT\log T$ (or finite but we know zeta has the infinitely many trivial zeroes already so that case is excluded); since the trivial zeroes are $O(T)$ and the non trivial ones are in the critical strip (functional equation again), the result follows

Comment: @Conrad, thanks for the comment, I now understand a bit more about entire functions, and their type and order, but I still don't see the connection between the $(s-1) \, \zeta(s)$ order one and its maximum type with the ever increasing density of zeros of $\zeta(s)$ with increasing  $|t|$ to be going with $T {\rm log} \, T$. Could you please provide some further insights and/or references for that development?

Comment: From Stirling, $\log |\Gamma(T+iM)|, T>0$ is about $T\log T$ for $|M| \le T$ (asymptotically speaking for $T$ large), while $\log |\Gamma(M\pm iT)| \ge -c\log T$ for $0 < M \le T$ (ie $\Gamma$ increases much faster on the positive axis, then it decreases vertically); by the functional equation we get that $\log |\zeta|$ increases very fast (like $T\log T$) on $|z|=T, \arg z \in (3\pi/4, 5\pi/4$ say, while it doesn't decrease that fast on the rest of the circle, so its average on the circle is still on the order of $T\log T$ and then Jensen theorem shows that the zeroes must be also $T \log T$

Comment: So yes, the argument is a bit more complicated than a simple order/type one but the idea is that the growth order of $\log |(s-1)\zeta|$ (which is, of course, the same as the growth order of $\log |\zeta|$ outside a small neighborhood of $1$) gives the growth order of the zeroes (note that this is not always true as $1/\Gamma$ grows like $T\log T$ too but it has $O(T)$ zeroes, however $\zeta$ is known to behave well in the right half-plane and the nature of the functional equation connects its behavior in the left half-plane with the behavior of $\Gamma (M+iN), M>0$ as above